# SwiftUI - NavigationLink' content is not readable when contextMenu is presented

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a coloured `NavigationLink` that has context-menu. Its content is not readable when the context-menu is presened. I have epxreminted using the  context-menu on the immediate sub-view of the `NavigationLink`, but it is stil the same issue.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("View")) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Context Menu")

            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 70)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .cornerRadius(3.0)
}
.background(Color.red)
.contextMenu {
    Section {
        Button(action: {
        }) {
            Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
        }
    }
    
    Section(header: Text("Secondary actions")) {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigatoinLinks** look like in its original state.

[image]

When the context-menu is presented. The problem is even worse If I use small sized text.

[image]

I have tested on ios 14.2 both on simulator and physical device.

---

#### Info

Hierarchy of views.

```
ScrollView {
  LazyVStack {
      ForEach(data) { item in
        // NavigationLink
      }
  }
}
```

---

#### Update

This is a similar project that has the same issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View")) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Context Menu")
                                    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                            }
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, idealHeight: 70)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .cornerRadius(3.0)
                        }
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Section {
                                Button(action: {
                                }) {
                                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Section(header: Text("Secondary actions")) {
                                Button(action: {}) {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce .. Xcode 12.2

Comment: Which iOS version do you have? I have this issue on ios 14.2 both on simulator and physical device.

Comment: Tested on simulator with 14.2. If I force press the View doesn't change. Stays the same and the text is fine. Okay just saw your hierarchy. I will test again. Maybe due to face being wrapped in ScrollView

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Could you provide standalone reproducible example?

Comment: I was able to reproduce on simulator 14.2 and 14.0.1 but interestingly enough on Canvas it does not happen. I moved the red background to the label vs the `NavigationLink` and it also Blurs. I think it has to do with the `.contextMenu` blurring everything except for the `NavigationLink` it does not see the `label` as something it should emphasize it sees it as all the other `View's so it Blurs/dims it.

Comment: @Asperi Included a similar example code.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been two years, but this still remains an issue with iOS 16 when you use LazyVStack. In contrast with List, SwiftUI generates a clear automatic preview. What's new with iOS 16 is that you can now define a custom preview, and SwiftUI will present that preview without the blur. If you choose to use LazyVStack for performance or another reason, this gives you an alternative, albeit with duplicate code.

From your example above, you would add:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("View")) {
    // View such as your VStack containing Text
}
.contextMenu {
    // Menu items
} preview: {
    // View, again, but you might want to simplify or modify 
}
```